# Not able to use Directory::getFiles() directly in the code

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to get few files from a path of specific pattern and for this I am using the command below which is giving me an error:

```
std::vector<std::string> cppFiles;
cppFiles = System::IO::Directory::GetFiles(path, "*.cpp" );
```

Error is on "System" and it says:- name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name.

I even tried putting using namespace System, still I am getting the same error on namespace as well.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obviously not including the relevant header.

Comment: What could be the relevant header? Why is a relevant header required here? As far as my knowledge, using namespace System::IO is pre-defined functionality of C++ which can be used directly.

Comment: System::IO is not standard `C++`. It's a `.Net` namespace/class library, only available on Microsoft platforms AFAICT.

Comment: So how can I go about this now?? My requirement is I want to get files from a directory into a vector...

Comment: tech_learning: please post the answer and mark the question as [RESOLVED], so it will help others and avoid them to waste time trying to help you further